# Using PHP to store results of a post request

Tags: php, http-post, file-writing

Im currently working with an API which requires we send our collection details in xml to their server using a post request.

Nothing major there but its not working, so I want to output the sent xml to a txt file so I can look at actually whats being sent!!

Instead of posting to the API im posting to a document called target, but the xml its outputting its recording seems to be really wrong. Here is my target script, note that the posting script posts 3 items, so the file being written should have details of each post request one after the other.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// get the request data...
$payload = '';
$fp = fopen('php://input','r');
$output_file = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $payload .= fgets($fp);
    fwrite($output_file, $payload);
}

fclose($fp);
fclose($output_file);
?>
```

I also tried the following, but this just recorded the last post request so only 1 collection item was recorded in the txt file, instead of all 3

```
output_file = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
while (!feof($fp)) {
    $payload .= fgets($fp);
}
fwrite($output_file, $payload);
fclose($fp);
fclose($output_file);
```

I know im missing something really obvious, but ive been looking at this all morning!

Comment: Shouldn't you be using fopen('output.txt', 'a'); -> append flag not write flag. Else you overwrite the file. no?

Comment: Yes thats the problem, told you I couldnt see it for the trees!! Its been a long morning. Post it as an answer and you have got your correct answer tick :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
$output_file = fopen('output.txt', 'w');
```

to

```
$output_file = fopen('output.txt', 'a');
```

Also, change

```
$payload .= fgets($fp);
```

to

```
$payload = fgets($fp);
```

Comment: or put fwrite($output_file, $payload); right after the while loop, not inside.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably use curl instead to fetch the content and then write it via fwrite

Answer (score 0):

change

```
  $payload .= fgets($fp);
```

to

```
 $payload = fgets($fp);
```